# Mixing static and dynamic libraries in Rust FFI

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My executable Rust crate uses a native library `libfoo.a` which depends on a shared library `libbar.so`, but does not expose it at all.

My Rust FFI uses the methods from libfoo, so I defined a `link` attribute on my extern code::

```
#[link(name="foo", kind="static")]
extern "C"{
    pub fn do_foo();
}
```

and my `build.rs` included from `Cargo.toml` using `build="build.rs"`

```
fn main() {
    let libs = &[(Some("../libs/foo/1.0/"), "static=foo"), // use ../libs/foo/1.0/libfoo.a
                 (None, "bar")]; // use libbar.so using LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    for &(ref m_path, ref lib) in libs {
        if let &Some(static_path) = m_path {
            println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", &static_path);
        }
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib={}", &lib);
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
cargo:rustc-link-search=../libs/foo/1.0/
cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=foo
cargo:rustc-link-lib=bar
```

Theoretically, I expect Rust to link against `libfoo.a` and `libbar.so`. The problem is that rustc does not even try to acknowledge `libbar`.

`cargo build --debug` ends with

```
/home/author/src/foo/foo.c:21: undefined reference to 'bar_do_stuff'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I inspect the linker command, there is an `-L ../libs/foo/1.0` argument, as well as `-l foo`, but there is no trace of `-l bar` !

If I manually add the `-l bar` to `cc`, it builds (and runs) just fine.

Could you let me know what I am missing? Should I create an FFI binding for `libbar` even though I don't use it in Rust and it is not exposed from libfoo's API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is a conflict between the `#[link]` attribute in the FFI definition and the output of the `build.rs` build script.

It would seem that the `#[link]` attribute is instructing `rustc` to ignore the `cargo:rustc-link-*` instructions.

The fix was as simple as removing the `#[link]` attribute.